# How to download image from dropbox without using api in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, dropbox-api

This is the http request from dropbox api explorer for Dropbox API Explorer • download

```
POST /2/files/download
Host: https://content.dropboxapi.com
User-Agent: api-explorer-client
Authorization: ACCESS-TOKEN
Dropbox-API-Arg: {"path":"image.jpg"}
```

I created a Alamofire request to download but it doesn't work

But when I create a Temporary Link and try to download it works.

Code for temp link download (working)

```html
let parameters: Parameters = [
            "path": requestedFilePath
        ]
        
        let urlString = AjaxRequestUrlList.getDropBoxTempLink
        Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: dropboxHeaderWithContentTypeJSON)
            .LogRequest()
            .responseJSON { response in
                if !response.result.isFailure{
                    var json = JSON(response.result.value!)
                    if json["link"].exists(){
                            Alamofire.download(json["link"].string!, to: destination).responseData { response in
                                if completionHandler != nil{
                                    completionHandler(true)
                                }
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        if completionHandler != nil{
                            completionHandler(false)
                        }
                    }
                }
                else{
                        if completionHandler != nil{
                        completionHandler(false)
                    }
                }
        }
```

```html
let dropboxHeaderWithContentTypeJSON: HTTPHeaders = [
    "Authorization": CS_App_Constants.dropboxAccessToken,
    "Content-Type" : "application/json"
    ]
```

But if I directly call https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download without getting temp link it fails

Comment: Could you Please show your code ?